# Error org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, build, jar, hadoop

I have a problem including the jars for reading a file from hadoop. If i run the application from netbeans, it works. But if i run it from command line
it succeeds building the jar but i cannot run it and i get the following exception. When i execute the programm i put also the path of the
jars.

> javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl not found

If i add in the list of jars xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar I get the next following exception.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/security/auth/UnixPrincipal

Does anyone has a clue of how i can solve this?

Comment: This is a very important question: The detail you added below, RE, that you ARE USING SUN is even more critical.  the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/security/auth/UnixPrincipal seems to also occur on Sun JVMs.  I wonder why and what the appropriate fix for this is !

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the fact that you're running the IBM JVM.

- switch to the Sun JVM, which is the only one that Hadoop is rigorously tested on

  OR
- Go to the IBM web site and download their slightly-modified version of Hadoop that works with their JVM.

I think that the issue might be fixed with the latest hadoop revisions.

Jira issues: [one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7211) and [two](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6941).
See [this](http://hadoop-common.472056.n3.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-com-sun-security-auth-UnixPrincipal-td2989927.html), [this](http://hadoop-common.472056.n3.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-com-sun-security-auth-UnixPrincipal-td2989927.html) and [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201105.mbox/%3C1306568727879-2995577.post@n3.nabble.com%3E)

Comment: I checked and I use Sun JVM. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: which hadoop version are u using ? if its old get the new one.

Comment: Can u give me the list of jars in your $HADOOP_HOME/lib folder ? maybe i can see if there are other jars which are required.

Comment: I am using hadoop-1.0.1. Here is the list with the jars that I use. In netbeans it worked to run JARS:./commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
./commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
./commons-cli-1.2.jar
./commons-codec-1.4.jar
./commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
./commons-configuration-1.6.jar
./commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar
./commons-digester-1.8.jar
./commons-el-1.0.jar
./commons-lang-2.4.jar
./commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
./commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar
./commons-math-2.1.jar
./commons-net-1.4.1.jar
./core-3.1.1.jar
./hadoop-ant-1.0.1.jar
./hadoop-client-1.0.1.jar
./hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar
./hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar